# how to read a frame from an easycap in ubuntu?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-14.04

I am using ubuntu 14.04. I have bought a easycap 4ch then I have followed [this](https://code.google.com/archive/p/easycap-somagic-linux/wikis/GettingStarted.wiki) instructions and finally I received this picture. could you tell me, how can I fix it?
[image]

I am going to do some processing on video stream with opencv. but I don't know how I can read data from the video in opencv. could you tell me what I should do?
thanks.